# Using the response of one Class into another

Tags: android, json, parsing, class, android-asynctask

I have created an application where I had extended an Activity and got the response from the Web Service Successfully using the Asynctask, Now I want to do the Json Parsing of that received Response in the another class other than in the main activity.

How can do that? How do I use the received Response of the Main Activity in a separate Class because in the next class I just want to do the Parsing using the Response achieved from the Main Class.

Can anybody please give me an answer of this!

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sent value to another class by passing to its constructor, or passing as any function arguments.

Or if you want to pass value to Asynctask class

```
 public class abc extends Activity {

 new AsynctaskClassName.execute(response);      
 }
```

And the Asynctask will be

```
 public class AsynctaskClassNameextends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {
 protected Z doInBackground(String... res){  
 ...  
  response = res[0]  
 ...   
}
```

Or to pass value to another intent, its better to pass by

```
    Intent.putExtra("response", response);
```

and read by

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String response = extras.getString("response");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new class

```
public class Parser
{
public static String rawJSON;
....
}
```

Now in your AsyncTask simply store JSON response in Parser.rawJSON like this

```
protected Z doInBackground(X...x){
...
Parser.rawJSON=responseFromServer(URL);
...
}
```

& you are done!

Comment: I had got the Response from the Web Service in my onPostExecute method of AsyncTask like this:
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
 {
  System.out.println("Output Response:----->" + result);
 }

Comment: Can I use the Result variable directly anywhere?

Comment: @david Nope, to use your result in Parser class use: void onPostExecute(String result) { System.out.println("Output Response:----->" + result); Parser.rawJSON= result}